# package.json "alias" entry

Tags: reactjs, npm, alias, package.json

I've been trying to create a React.js shared library which could be reused across the monorepo. Ultimately all the solutions required linking the React module installed in the library's directory by the projects, to avoid its duplication.

I've found a working example generated by TSDX (https://tsdx.io/). It seems to do the linking job with an *alias* entry in the *package.json* file, however I can't find the documentation reference anywhere.

Where does that entry come from? What does it specifically do? If it's TS related, how to achieve the same with JS?

Here's my package.json file, which comes from the generated project's *example* subdirectory

```
{
  "name": "example",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "parcel index.html",
    "build": "parcel build index.html"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react-app-polyfill": "^1.0.0",
    "shared-library": "file:../shared-library"
  },
  "alias": {
    "react": "../shared-library/node_modules/react",
    "react-dom": "../shared-library/node_modules/react-dom/profiling",
    "scheduler/tracing": "../shared-library/node_modules/scheduler/tracing-profiling"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.0.28",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.11",
    "parcel": "1.12.3",
    "typescript": "^3.4.5"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer was in git's history. It's Parcel's feature.
https://github.com/jaredpalmer/tsdx/blame/master/templates/react/example/package.json